# Java application getting projects and their associations from MS Project Server 2013

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey-client, ms-project-server-2013

I want to use the REST api of a locally installed MS Project Server 2013 in order to get all projects and their associations(tasks, deliverables and resources) so that I will bind them with the business model of my custom J2ee application. So, I have 2 questions:

1. According to what I've read so far in MS Project Server documentation, I can use either ProjectData service or ProjectServer resource. What is considered more appropriate for my case?
2. Can anyone give me a simple example of getting projects and their associations using a Jersey client? Would something like the below be correct using the ProjectData service?

> ```
> String url = "http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/$metadata"; 
> Client client = Client.create();
> WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
> ClientResponse response=webResource.accept("application/xml")
> .get(ClientResponse.class); 
> String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. ProjectData provides OData read-only access to the 38 entities for reporting. ProjectServer provides the main functionality of the Project Server Interface (PSI) for the primary entities.
2. For OData service, I use Apache Olingo library:
   https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/index.html